# javascript inheritance by prototype chaining didnt working

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I follow the book of Stoyan Stefanov JavaScript Patterns ans have a stuck... I cant inherit the prototype. Why? What I do wrong? (run this code on NodeJS)

```
// inheritance
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'some Name';
}

Parent.prototype.say = () => this.name;

function Child(name) {
  // this.name = '123';
}

function inherit(C, P) {
  C.prototype = new P();
}
inherit(Child, Parent);
debug(Child.prototype);

const kid = new Child();
debug(kid);
debug(kid.name);
debug(kid.say());
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not intended to use as methods. `Parent.prototype.say` should be normal function instead.

Comment: `() => this.name;` is using the declaration context rather than the Parent's context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions are not intended to be used as methods. `Parent.prototype.say` should be normal function instead. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not have its own `this`**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for **non-method**
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

```js
// inheritance
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'some Name';
}

Parent.prototype.say = function() { // normal function
  return this.name;
};

function Child(name) {
  // this.name = '123';
}

function inherit(C, P) {
  C.prototype = new P();
}
inherit(Child, Parent);
console.log(Child.prototype);

const kid = new Child();
console.log(kid);
console.log(kid.name);
console.log(kid.say());
```

Comment: And Eslint says to not use unnamed function. Its just cuz of AirBnb linting syntax?

Comment: Well you could add a name to it. :) `function say() {`